# Riddle whose answer is children

Tags: puzzle-creation

I would like to find good What Am I riddles whose answer is a child/children. (As in filiation, not kids as in young people.) Or even an answer such as "legacy". I have tried to search for them online but even with advanced search I only get results like Easy Riddles for Kids!! or other riddles about children that are not what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 2):

This is still in rough draft phases, but this is my try:

> I'm a dwarf of the world
>   But still in sight
>   People take care of me
>   But I put up a fight
>   They think I'm too small
>   To go out in the world
>   But after a while
>   I grow and grow
>   Until I am dwarf no more
>   Ready to venture out and explore
>   What am I?